# How to close severals showDialogs in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, flutter-dialog

How can I to close all the `showDialog`s in my aplication? in this case `_mostrarDialogConfirmacion` is the dialog where i request to the user a confirmation to make a query, `cargandoDialog` is another dialog where i show a loading message while the query is executing, when the query finish, i want to close the two dialogs and only see the `_mostrarDialogMensaje` dialog

```dart
_mostrarDialogConfirmacion(
  mensaje, 
  BuildContext context, 
  codLink, 
  motivo,
) {
  return showDialog(
    context: context, 
    builder: (context){
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text(
          'Informacion', 
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget> [
            Text(mensaje, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget> [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              cargandoDialog(context);
              List<dynamic> ingresarReclamo1 = await ingresarReclamo
                  .ingresarReclamo(codLink, titular, motivo);
              // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
              _mostrarDialogMensaje(
                ingresarReclamo1[0].observaciones,
                ingresarReclamo1[0].validado, 
                context,
              );
            }, 
            child: const Text('Si')
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: ()=> Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            child: const Text('No')
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to closing all  dialogs on `Si` tap?

Answer (score 1):

you will `dismiss` first dialog and then you can use `whenComplete` to dismiss the second dialog

```
showDialog(
  .....
).whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop())
```

Comment: where do i agree this line ? .whenComplete(() => Navigator.of(context).pop())
i the first showDialog or in the second?

Comment: in the last shown dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can return bool while `.pop(boolValue)` to check the tap button. Also, the `showDialog` is a future method, you can use `await` until it finished and then processed to next dialog. Navigator.of(context).pop() will be used to close recent dialog on this case.  As for my understanding about the question, try this example code.

```dart
 _mostrarDialogConfirmacion(mensaje, BuildContext context, codLink, motivo) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Informacion', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            content: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    // Navigator.of(context)
                    //     .pop(); //if you like to close previous one before showing the next dialog
                    final bool isSi = await showDialog(
                        barrierDismissible: false,
                        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                              content: Text("Second Dialog"),
                              actions: [
                                TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                                    },
                                    child: const Text('Si')),
                                TextButton(
                                    onPressed: () =>
                                        Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                                    child: const Text('No')),
                              ],
                            ),
                        context: context);
                    if (mounted && isSi) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      await showDialog(
                          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                              content: Text("_mostrarDialogMensaje")),
                          context: context);
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Si')),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: const Text('No')),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```